# Mysql Query order by multiple items(statments)

Tags: mysql

This is what I already have.

```
SELECT karma
     , profanity
     , username 
  FROM users 
 ORDER 
    BY (karma - profanity) DESC 
 LIMIT 10
```

how can I order by `ORDER BY (karma - profanity) DESC LIMIT 10`
and `ORDER BY profanity DESC LIMIT 10`

```
CREATE TABLE Test
    (`id` int, `username` varchar(55), `karma` int,`profanity` int)
;

INSERT INTO Test
    (`id`, `username`, `karma`, `profanity`)
VALUES
    (1, 'User1', '10', '1'),
    (2, 'User2', '8', '2'),
    (3, 'User3', '1', '2'),
    (4, 'User4', '11', '1'),
    (5, 'User5', '5', '0'),
    (6, 'User6', '6', '3'),
    (7, 'User7', '1', '1'),
    (8, 'User8', '2', '3'),
    (9, 'User9', '2', '1'),
    (10, 'User10', '1', '7'),
    (11, 'User11', '7', '7'),
    (12, 'User12', '1', '1'),
    (13, 'User13', '10', '0'),
    (14, 'User14', '1', '3'),
    (15, 'User15', '7', '0')
;
```

Desired Results will look like this:

```
karma, profanity, username | profanity  username
   10          0  User13             7  User11
   11          1  User4              7  User10
   10          1  User1              3  User8
    7          0  User15             3  User6
    8          2  User2              3  User14
    5          0  User5              2  User3
    6          3  User6              2  User2
    2          1  User9              1  User4
    1          1  User7              1  User7
    1          1  User12             1  User9
```

both having an output `result[i].(karma - profanity) and result[i].profanity)`

Both ordering combined into one having the order different callout

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ca828/2

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ca828/2

Comment: There ya go. I upvote for fiddles. @Strawberry take it away

Comment: Hope this has enough information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is veering towards a display issue - the kind of thing you'd normally resolve in application level code, but anyway...

```
SELECT a.karma a_karma
     , a.profanity a_profanity
     , a.username a_username
     , b.profanity b_profanity
     , b.username b_username
  FROM
     ( SELECT *,@kp:=@kp+1 kp FROM test, (SELECT @kp:=0) vars ORDER BY karma-profanity DESC LIMIT 10 ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT *,@p:=@p+1 p FROM test, (SELECT @p:=0) vars ORDER BY profanity DESC LIMIT 10 ) b
    ON b.p = a.kp;
+---------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| a_karma | a_profanity | a_username | b_profanity | b_username |
+---------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
|      10 |           0 | User13     |           7 | User11     |
|      11 |           1 | User4      |           7 | User10     |
|      10 |           1 | User1      |           3 | User8      |
|       7 |           0 | User15     |           3 | User6      |
|       8 |           2 | User2      |           3 | User14     |
|       5 |           0 | User5      |           2 | User3      |
|       6 |           3 | User6      |           2 | User2      |
|       2 |           1 | User9      |           1 | User4      |
|       1 |           1 | User7      |           1 | User7      |
|       1 |           1 | User12     |           1 | User9      |
+---------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're smoking there @Drew, but save some for me.;-)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed.